# How can I extract network coefficients from tensorflow .ckpt into .npy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, transform, checkpoint

I am working with the FasterRCNN tensorflow implementation found [HERE](https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF). When defining the 'train_net' function, in the file train.py, they define a saver with the following command:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=100, write_version=saver_pb2.SaverDef.V1)
```

As a result, at the end of a training run, a number of .ckpt files are created in the output folder, each one containing the model coefficients snapshot for (by default) every 5000 training iteration steps. 
Now, if you try to run the testing process (or if you like to continue training) you have 2 choices for loading a pre-trained model. Either you load one such .ckpt file or you can, alternatively, load an .npy file such as the popular [VGG_imagenet.npy](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByuDEGFYmWsbNVF5eExySUtMZmM/view) (the 2 cases are handled in the function 'load' in the class 'Network' defined in the file 'network.py'.

Is there some way to transform the network coefficients saved in the .ckpt file into an .npy file with the structure of VGG_imagenet.npy? Can I obtain this by importing some lines of code right after the .ckpt info is loaded (in the initialize variables section of SolverWrapper>train_model() in the file train.py)?

Thank you.